# How to count the occurences in this dataset with SQL

Tags: sql

Hello I need to know the sql code on this question:

How many students did participate the examcode DBS21 more than twice?

This is the R code of it:

```
  beoordeling %>% 
  filter(examcode == "DBS21", !is.na(resultaat)) %>% 
  group_by(studentnr) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2) %>% 
  summarise()
```

I'll give a smaller version of the dataset, (I removed a column called 'resultaat' since it's not important for the question.

Thanks alot!

| studentnr | examcode | periode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201001 |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 101 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 101 | ICB21 | 201001 |
| 102 | ICB21 | 201001 |
| 103 | DBS21 | 201001 |
| 103 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 104 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 104 | ICB21 | 201003 |
| 105 | DBS21 | 201003 |
| 105 | DBS21 | 201101 |
| 105 | ICB21 | 201003 |

The output should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT studentnr
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY studentnr
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN examcode = 'DBS21' THEN 1 END) > 2;
```

You could also use a filtering approach:

```sql
SELECT studentnr
FROM yourTable
WHERE examcode = 'DBS21'
GROUP BY studentnr
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use where filter for DBS21

```
select studentnr from table_name
where examcode='DBS21'
group by studentnr
having count(1)>2
```